# How is it possible in JS to pass the check "variable.length > 0", but get "variable.map is undefined"?

Tags: javascript

I use Autocomplete from Material UI. There is a place where I get the error "value.map is undefined": https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.14/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L341. And there is a check at line 329 `value.length > 0`.

So for some reason, the value passes the check "length > 0", but doesn't have the `map` function. I have only a screenshot of the error, so can't debug via `console.log`.

I wonder, how is it possible? Of course, it could be an object `{length: 10}`, but it's unlikely. Are there other options?

Comment: It could be a string. You could use the JavaScript debugger to see what the variable is at runtime.

Comment: indeed, thanks. I didn't think about this because a string shouldn't be there at all, but who knows

Comment: value.length > 0 doesn’t  mean that you can iterate over value. You can check : `typeof value[Symbol.iterator] === 'function'`